# Oracle SQL Numeric Value to find 10 Charcters

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried the following and it worked

select  VendorID
from    Vendor
where   regexp_like (Vendor_name || Vendor_Secondary_name || Vendor_Alt_name,'\d')
;

And also is there an way to get 10 numeric words from the Name ? for example I do not need the Names like 2ABC, 9street. I only need 23 ave, 123 street.(

I have a `Vendor` table with the following fields

```
VendorID                Varchar2(50),
Vendor_Name             Varchar2(250),
Vendor_Secondary_Name   Varchar2(250),
Vendor_Alt_name         Varchar2(250);
```

With the following Data:

```
VendorID    Vendor_name      Vendor_Secondary_name  Vendor_Alt_name
123         1258968954 Alpha        Alpha                  Beta Alpha
456         Sigma Solutuion  Sigma suite 9500       Sigma
789         Beta pvt Ltd     Beta LTD               Beta Alpha
5899        ABC              ABC INFO               ABC  IN 698545896
1222        XYZ              XYZ                    XYZ Inc
```

I need a SQL query to find all the Vendor IDs where any of the name fields has a numeric value. In this case I need the following to be in my output:

```
123
```

5899

### EDIT

SQL copied from comment:

```
select *
  from vendor
  where REGEXP_LIKE ((Vendor_name, '^[0-9]*$') or
        REGEXP_LIKE (Vendor_secondary_name, '^[0-9]*$') or
        REGEXP_LIKE (vendor_alt_name, '^[0-9]*$'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not a code-writing service. Show us your best effort and tell us what errors you're getting and perhaps someone can help. Best of luck.

Comment: I tried the following but it's not picking all the rows.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 select * from vendor where REGEXP_LIKE ((Vendor_name, '^[0-9]*$') or REGEXP_LIKE (Vendor_secondary_name, '^[0-9]*$') or REGEXP_LIKE (vendor_alt_name, '^[0-9]*$'));

Comment: Please *edit the question* to show what you tried and what was wrong with it - don't just add as comments.

Comment: Your patterns are anchored with `^` and `$`, so you are only looking for strings which are entirely made up of numeric digits. From your examples that isn't what you intended? Also do you need stand-alone numbers; would you want, say, `3M` to match?

Comment: Besides the "requirement clarification" in Alex's comment (do you need to select the vendor ID if you can find something like CM84 in one of the names)? and the mistake he pointed out about anchoring, there is another mistake: after you remove the `^` and `$` everything will match, because you will have `[0-9]*` left, and that matches any number of digits, INCLUDING ZERO. You need `[0-9]+`, which means ONE or more consecutive digits. Or, even simpler, you just need to match `[0-9]` (once, you don't care if there is more than one digit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  VendorID        
from    Vendor     
where   regexp_like (' ' || Vendor_name || ' ' || Vendor_Secondary_name || ' ' || Vendor_Alt_name || ' ','\s\d{10}\s')
;
```

Comment: Awesome that worked thanks a lot.  And also Is there an way to get only numeric words from the Name for Example If the Name is 20ABC I don't need it. I need which are 20 ABC or 30 XYZ

Comment: You need to add spaces between the concatenated names, too.

Comment: Awesome Thanks a lot. Is there an way just to find if the Numeric value is 10 Characters with in the Name  ?

Comment: @KumarG, please give an example

Comment: Say if the Vendor Names are  ABC 5869568971, SAM 8958214569, JOE 4040235689, STEVE 1456987. I should be only getting first 3 Names. Where Numeric value has 10 characters

Comment: @KumarG, please also edit the question so it will match the answer

Comment: Awesome.Thanks alot